# dns.lookup() Function keeps resolving host names as 0.0.0.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, networking, dns

I am writing a function that will return the IP address of a hostname using the lookup function in the dns Node.js library.

Here is my function code:

```
const dns = require('dns');

export function resolveIPV4Address(hostname) {
    let ipv4Address = "";
    dns.lookup(hostname, (error, address) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`Error resolving host ${hostname}: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }

        if (address.length === 0) {
            console.error(`No IP addresses found for ${hostname}`);
            return;
        }

        ipv4Address = address.toString();
    });
    return ipv4Address;
}
```

When the function is ran, an IP address of 0.0.0.0 is returned.

I've tried using many different host names. I started by using some local host names within my network, but those didn't work. I tested the host names in the terminal by pinging them and using nslookup, and they resolved fine.

I then tried using some public domain names such as google.com with no luck.

I also tried to pass in 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as an argument for the dns.lookup() function.

I changed the DNS settings on my network adapter on my PC. I made the primary DNS address 8.8.8.8 and the secondary 8.8.4.4.

I use OpenDNS as my network's DNS server. I turned off all content filtering, but that did not seem to work. I also checked the firewall on my ISP's router, and nothing was being blocked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You are returning before the callback completes. Anyway, I ran your code with a simple modification, It is working just fine. Please check the `node` and the `nslookup` using the same DNS settings. If not tell the node to use the right server using [setServers()](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dnssetserversservers) method.

```
const dns = require('dns');

function resolveIPV4Address(hostname) {
    let ipv4Address = "";
    dns.lookup(hostname, (error, address) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`Error resolving host ${hostname}: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }

        if (address.length === 0) {
            console.error(`No IP addresses found for ${hostname}`);
            return;
        }

        console.log(address.toString());
    });
}

resolveIPV4Address("google.com");
```